# Simple search is not working in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I set up a search mechanism for my Procedure table following this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form?autoplay=true.  I pretty much followed it exactly but I get this error when I submit the search:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /procedures

Couldn't find all Procedures with 'id': (all, {:conditions=>["name LIKE ?", "%Emergency%"]}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)
```

I want to search for Procedures by name, and this error makes it look like it is searching by id?

Here is the view:

```
      <%= form_tag procedures_path, :method => 'get' do %>
      <p>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :id => "welcome-search" %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search Procedures", :name => nil, :class => "btn btn-success btn-lg" %>
```

My controller:

```
def index
  @procedures = Procedure.search(params[:search])
  render `procedures/index`
end
```

My model:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
  find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
else
  find(:all)
end
end
```

I'm pretty confused since the railscast makes it look so easy to get working..Thanks.

Comment: What rails version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find(:all)` is very old and is no longer available since rails 3.2. Instead use `where`:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    all
  end
end
```

Comment: Anyone frowning from having to use SQL string can check this out: `scope :matching, -> (search) { arel_table[:name].matches "%#{search}%" }` ...and ponder if it's worth it.